# Saved image render has a more washed out color compared to the render result on blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, filmic-blender

After rendering image in blender the result came out with a more washed out not as saturated image compared the one in blender render window

This is the only setting I've tweaked during the render process:

Color management
Look: very high contrast

Some additional infos:
Engine: Cycles
Device: Mac OS Laptop

the rest are the same as default settings
Attached below are the difference in color, it may be quite minimal however this really changed the end tune quite a bit.

This is how it look in blender render window (more saturated and nice)
[image]

This is my current render result (as you can see it is more desaturated compared to how it looks in blender
[image]

Comment: Color Management > Filmic I guess ... Blender keeps render as Linear (uncropped data) before save. If you save into a PNG format it is cropped into 8 bit. Try to save as OpenEXR 32 bit (fulll float) to see if it makes a difference. Or try to place your saved image into into blender's image editor next to render result editor to compare them.

Comment: Thank you for replying @vklidu! Indeed I used filmic, I've also tried your suggestion using openEXR and the result are crazy clear and after comparing the saved image next to the render result it turns out it's the same (all of the washed out saturation are no more) may I know what does this mean and how I may be able to fix this saturation problem?

Comment: When I wrote "or" I meant to compare in blender your saved file in format used in your Q. To see if it is not an issue of app you used to view your saved image. In general you can't get exact result for file format that supports cropped color range, that 8-bit color depth definetly is ... BTW I just noticed your saved image is just at Index color space (256 color table) I don't think you can expect more from this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem because of the way Mac displays are built, and here's my solution that doesn't involve downloading a bunch of other stuff. It's not perfect, but it gets pretty close.

1. When saving the image change your colour management to *Override*
2. Increase the *Exposure* to a value between `0.3` to `0.5`
3. Change the *Gamma* to a value between `0.7` to `0.8`

I think this is because for Mac displays the gamma tends to be turned up quite a bit.

It's not perfect, so play around with the values a bit more to suit your colours.